# A conjecture inspired by a famous contest problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, conjectures, vieta-jumping

There is a famous difficult problem:

For all natural numbers $a,b$ it's true that:
$\displaystyle(ab+1)|(a^2+b^2)\implies \frac{a^2+b^2}{ab+1}$ is a
perfect square.

I've noticed $(a=1,\dots 100)$ that for each $a$ there's a $b$ such that
$(ab+1)|(a^2+b^2)$ and my question is if this can be proved generally? Induction seems to lead nowhere.

Comment: Based on 1988 IMO problem 6?

Comment: $$(ab+1)|(a^2+b^2)\to (ab+a+b+2)|(a^2+2a+1+b^2+2b+1)$$ is it true ? at least for the same value of a and b ?

Comment: @SeanRoberson, yes.

Comment: Google for Vieta jumping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first  guaranteed value is $$ b = a^3  $$ which gives
$$ \frac{a^2 + b^2}{ab+1} = \frac{a^2 + a^6}{a^4 + 1} = a^2 $$